# Hibernate does not create tables - Spring Boot

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

I set `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update` but when I run spring boot the tables are not created. I want it to update the bank automatically.

Some settings:

`application.properties`:

```
## Spring DATASOURCE (DataSourceAutoConfiguration & DataSourceProperties)

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pell

spring.datasource.username = daniel

spring.datasource.password = root


## Hibernate Properties

# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database


spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect


# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update


spring.jpa.show-sql = true
```

Some beans:

```
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pell");
    dataSource.setUsername("daniel");
    dataSource.setPassword("root");
    factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    factoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"eu.pell.models"});

    JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);

    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.ddl-auto", "update");
    properties.setProperty("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
    factoryBean.setJpaProperties(properties);

    return factoryBean;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}

@Bean
public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation() {
    return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
}
```

Comment: you got any error? if no error then make sure your Spring boot Main class scan's your entities to create tables.

Comment: Are you sure that your tables are not already existing in database?

Comment: Did you managed to solve the issue?